# How to check if android view has any TouchListeners

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

How can I check if a view has registered an `OnTouchClickListener` or not?

For example I can do this for `OnClickListerner` with the following code:

```
if (view.hasOnClickListeners()){
 //do something
}
```

I want to do something similar for `TouchClickListener`.  Is this possible?

Comment: What is an OnTouchClickListener? Did you mean `View.OnTouchListener`?

Comment: What is your purpose exactly? What do you want to do with the info whether the view has any TouchListeners or not ? Maybe that purpose can be fulfilled other way.